# How to deselect a table's head and certain tds with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

I want to create a html table of which I want to select only the cells that do not belong to the thead and do not have a certain class. I got stuck with the not operating selector like this

```
table :not(thead):not(.cell-class) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|                |               |          |          |    <-- <thead>
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|  .cell-class   |       x       |     x    |     x    |
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|  .cell-class   |       x       |     x    |     x    |
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|  .cell-class   |  .cell-class  |     x    |     x    |
+----------------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

Only the x marked cells are supposed to be selected. Does anyone know how to address it properly?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to select the `thead`, or not select it? (It doesn't really make sense to select a table grouping element together with a bunch of table cells anyway.)

Comment: @ BoltClock: No, I don't want to select the <thead>. ONLY the x marked cells. And I do NOT want to select a grouping element together with anything else. I especially want to exclude it from the selected ones.

Comment: I edited your question. It originally said "select the thead" which was why I was confused.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the correction. I've also fixed the text below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this

```
tbody td:not(.cell-class) {
    background: #ffffff; 
}
```

It should even work if you don't have an additional `tbody`-element enclosing your `tr`s after the `thead`. (At least it does in chrome tested with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr5ramfp/1/).)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is it! The reason for all this, I want to create a gradient background-color for headline(s) and the key column(s) for the whole size of the table, not only for the cells having their own gradients. With this special select I now can address all the value cells (what is x marked here) to have different background color.

Answer (score 2):

The following selector syntax should do what you're looking for:

```
thead, td:not(.cell-class){

}
```

Comment: This also selects the thead, which are not supposed to be selected.

Comment: Unfortunately your question states that you actually do want to select the thead.

Comment: In fact the question is ambiguous. In the beginning it's stated that thead should be selected, but the title and the diagram below seem to imply that it's not the case. I was also very confused.

Comment: You are right, at least partially: In my first sentence I forgot to mention that I do want to exclude the <thead> as well. Sorry. Regarding this reading your css selection seems to be an appropriate one. Thanks for your help.